# 401 Error When Attempting to Stream Tweets from Twitter API using Tweepy

Tags: python, api, twitter, tweepy, twitterapi-python

I am attempting to stream tweets from the Twitter API module using the Tweepy Python library.

I have watched several tutorials and they all give the same code.

However, it keeps producing a 401 error. Here is the code I am using.

It would be great if someone could highlight where I might be going wrong.

```
from tweepy.streaming import StreamListener
from tweepy import OAuthHandler
from tweepy import Stream
from tweepy import API


Access_Token = "A"
Access_Token_Secret = "B"
Consumer_Key = "C"
Consumer_Key_Secret = "D"

auth = OAuthHandler(Consumer_Key, Consumer_Key_Secret)
auth.set_access_token(Access_Token, Access_Token_Secret)
api = API(auth)

class StdOutListener(StreamListener):

def on_data(self, data):
    print(data)
    return True

def on_error(self, status):
    print(status)

if __name__ == '__main__':

listener = StdOutListener()
auth = OAuthHandler(Consumer_Key, Consumer_Key_Secret)
auth.set_access_token(Access_Token, Access_Token_Secret)
stream = Stream(auth, listener)

stream.filter(track=['bitcoin', 'btc', 'trump','election','biden'])
```